# how to calculate number with date in sql oracle cmd

Tags: sql, oracle

so i try this

```
select sr.member, 
       sr.code_book,
       bk.title_book, 
       sr.return_date,
       (kg.borrowed_time - sr.borrow_date) as target back
from sirkulasi sr, 
     book bk, 
     kategori kg
where sr.code_book = bk.code_book 
  and sr.return_date = '';
```

but it say inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

because the length of the loan is the number and the date of the loan is the date

the question is like this
Show circulation information that has not returned and when it is targeted to return
(The feature that has not returned is the data in the circulation table which is still dated
empty, the return target is calculated based on borrowed_time and borrowed_date according to
category)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sr.return_date = ''` is never true in Oracle if `return_date` is a varchar column. You need to use `sr.return_date is null` instead. And if that really is a `varchar` then the question is: why are you storing date values in `varchar` columns?

Comment: nvm i already found it thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Second, the only part of the query that could generate the error is the `-`.  I'm pretty sure you want:

```
select sr.member, sr.code_book, bk.title_book, sr.return_date,
       (sr.borrow_date + kg.borrowed_time ) as target_back
from sirkulasi sr join
     book bk
     sr.code_book = bk.code_book
where sr.return_date is null;
```

Notes:

- The target return date is (presumably) the borrowed day by the length of time.  `+` is allowed between a date and a number, when first operand is a date and the second a number that represents a number of days.
- `return_date` certainly should be a `date`.  Non-returns should be `NULL` values not strings.  A string is not even appropriate for a date comparison.  And `= ''` never evaluates to "true" in Oracle because Oracle (mistakenly) treats an empty string as `NULL`.
- The table `kategori` is not used in the query.  Remove it.
- `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.